# WPF how to filter data-binded element? MVVM related

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, mvvm

I've got a textbox and it's Text property bound to a string(in the view model)

Question: How do I make it so whatever is written in that textbox is exactly 10 characters long (or only in English letters, just an example).

Problem is it is directly written to the viewModel's string variable. So my only idea is having a converter for this. But even if the converter returns nothing, how do I inform the user that something's wrong? ("error - length != 10" as an example)

Comment: Its more useful to think of the problem as validation as opposed to filtering. WPF provides several flavors of support as one of the answers here shows, but IDataErrorInfo is the preferred approach for MVVM (see Adi Lester's answer). Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I recommend having a look at the [`IDataErrorInfo` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx).
You can have your viewmodel implement this interface to define the validation logic. For example:

```cs
public class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string MyText { get; set; }

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "MyText")
            {
                if (MyText.Length != 10)
                {
                    return "Text should be exactly 10 letters.";
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

A good example and further customization can be found [here](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [WPF Data Validation](http://wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html)

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.